# how many key value pairs an object can handle?

Tags: javascript, json

I've 3 million lead objects and 5 thousand program objects, which will be mapped together using program activity, hence a lead object will have multiple program objects. So my question is can I store 3 million leads holding their programs in a single object?

eg:

```
{
     "lead78354": {
         "First Name": "test",
         "Last Name": "test",
         "Id": "78354",
         "Email Address": "webintegtest.gb_3.1412@yopmail.com",
         "FirstLeadSource": "null",
         "leadStatus": "Qualified",
         "country": "US",
         "SEInferredCountry": "null",
         "LastProgramSuccess": "null",
         "HistoryOfProgramSuccesses": "Dec 14, 2017 : US_All_Contact_Sale",
         "programs": {
             "program1": {
                 "id": 1324,
                 "description": "•\tContent selection  LP & TY",
                 "createdAt": "2015-02-27T15:18:31Z+0000",
                 "updatedAt": "2017-12-17T15:09:39Z+0000",
                 "type": "Default",
                 "channel": "Content",
                 "folder": {
                     "type": "Folder",
                     "value": 7685,
                     "folderName": "US Country Pages"
                 },
                 "status": "",
                 "workspace": "NAM",
                 "tags": [{
                     "tagType": "Marketing Campaign",
                     "tagValue": "EcoBuildings"
                 }, {
                     "tagType": "Primary Business",
                     "tagValue": "All Business Units"
                 }, {
                     "tagType": "Primary Country",
                     "tagValue": "US"
                 }, {
                     "tagType": "Primary Market Segmentation",
                     "tagValue": "All Segments"
                 }],
                 "costs": []
             }
         }
     },
     lead2:{
            "test":"test"
            programs:{.......}
     }
   so on....
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it, what happened? What - if anything - went wrong, and in what way?

Comment: Shure. The maximum maximum limit is probably 9007199254740991

Comment: It is not extremely big JSON string, but parsing it to an object in a browser may take more memory than a browser is allowed to use.

Comment: The question should not be "can I?".  It should be "should I?", and the answer is a huge "no".  But in answer to the question, `how many key value pairs an object can handle?`.  I do know it's over 9,000.

Comment: Why would a single html page ever need all the data from 3 million records, though.  If it's a report it's better to condense it in a server/database setting, and if it's a UI then it's just too much, noone needs a list of 3 million somethings on one page.  Also, think of how long it's gonna take to transmit your obscenely large JSON file.  And thirdly, if record order is important, you should be using an array rather than an object.

Comment: am building a middleware which maps leads to programs. Initially ill have 1 lead CSV file and programs CSV file, and i wanna create an object of leads holding their programs in a single object as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.  All you have to do is create an object and then add new objects with unique IDs.  I've included a snippet below. The only constraint here seems to be your RAM.

```js
var allobjects = {};
var sampleObj = {
         "First Name": "test",
         "Last Name": "test",
         "Id": "78354",
         "Email Address": "webintegtest.gb_3.1412@yopmail.com",
         "FirstLeadSource": "null",
         "leadStatus": "Qualified",
         "country": "US",
         "SEInferredCountry": "null",
         "LastProgramSuccess": "null",
         "HistoryOfProgramSuccesses": "Dec 14, 2017 : US_All_Contact_Sale",
         "programs": {
             "program1": {
                 "id": 1324,
                 "description": "•\tContent selection  LP & TY",
                 "createdAt": "2015-02-27T15:18:31Z+0000",
                 "updatedAt": "2017-12-17T15:09:39Z+0000",
                 "type": "Default",
                 "channel": "Content",
                 "folder": {
                     "type": "Folder",
                     "value": 7685,
                     "folderName": "US Country Pages"
                 },
                 "status": "",
                 "workspace": "NAM",
                 "tags": [{
                     "tagType": "Marketing Campaign",
                     "tagValue": "EcoBuildings"
                 }, {
                     "tagType": "Primary Business",
                     "tagValue": "All Business Units"
                 }, {
                     "tagType": "Primary Country",
                     "tagValue": "US"
                 }, {
                     "tagType": "Primary Market Segmentation",
                     "tagValue": "All Segments"
                 }],
                 "costs": []
             }
         }
     };
     
 for (var i=0;i<3000000;i++) {
  allobjects[("lead"+i)]=Object.create(sampleObj);
 }
 
 var count =0;
 for (var prop in allobjects) {
 count++;
 }
 console.log("lead count: " + count);
```

Comment: you mean there is no memory limit for an object?

Comment: The memory limit is a browser limitation.  If you're running a 32 bit browser, your limit will be somewhere around 2GB.  If you're running 64gb, it's much higher. You can see in the snippet that I posted contains 3 million clones of your object, so if it runs for you, you have enough memory :D

Comment: am building a middleware which maps leads to programs.so I hope I can continue with no fear.this process runs over server.